# Can the mapping of the function keys change on a per-app basis on windows

Tags: keyboard, windows, keybindings

I would like to know if there is a third party application or other automation that can remap the keyboard based on the current application.

For example in terminal or you favourite IDE you want to use them as standard function keys but for other applications you want to keep the default media playback assignments.

Comment: Do you mean like [Using Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)?  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Hint: The first answer in the linked question works well. Tell us when you have tried it.

Comment: Windows question are off-topic here.